# jQuery UI with MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have ASP.Net MVC 4 Internet Application and I am using 'redmond' jQuery UI for it. I tried all the steps suggested at 
http://jqueryuihelpers.apphb.com/Docmo/GettingStarted

still only, Dialog and Framework Icons are visible in UI theme all other controls are in normal theme.

I copied the redmond folder in~/ Content/themes folder.
Copied the .js files in ~/scripts folder.

Added following bundle in BundleConfig.cs,

```
bundles.add(new stylebundle("~/content/themes/base/css").include(
    "~/content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css",
    "~/content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css"));
```

Added following reference in Site.Master of MVC 4 application,

```
<link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css") %>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I tried using the jQuery UI in Razor view engine as well as in ASPX (C#) view engine, both are showing only Dialog and Framework Icons in jQuery UI theme, all other controls like buttons and accordion etc. are not in jQuery UI theme.

Any guesses, what might have happened?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following scripts to the head instead of the body

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") 

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```